# Making text appear above the static picture slider on the Alt homepage, with static slider template on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Basically I'm making a site on Wordpress using the Wordpress theme "Restaurateur".  As you can see on the demo home page here http://wprestaurateur.com/ using the Alt homepage with static slider template, below the navigation is the picture slider and then below that some text.  I've basically completed the site except I want the text to show up first and then have the picture slider below it.  I've tried all I can think of with no luck.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

EDIT:  Added the .php file for the template im using for the home page.

```
<div id="content" class="clearfix">

    <div id="main" class="clearfix sldr" role="main">

        <div id="slide-wrap">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <div id="load-cycle"></div>
          <div class="cycle-slideshow alt-static" <?php 
                if ( get_theme_mod('restaurateur_slider_effect') ) {
                    echo 'data-cycle-fx="' . wp_kses_post( get_theme_mod('restaurateur_slider_effect') ) . '" data-cycle-tile-count="10"';
                } else {
                    echo 'data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz"';
                }
              ?> data-cycle-slides="> div.slides" <?php
                if ( get_theme_mod('restaurateur_slider_timeout') ) {
                    $slider_timeout = wp_kses_post( get_theme_mod('restaurateur_slider_timeout') );
                    echo 'data-cycle-timeout="' . $slider_timeout . '000"';
                } else {
                    echo 'data-cycle-timeout="3000"';
                }
              ?> >

        <div class="cycle-pager"></div>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php if ( has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'gallery' ) )  : ?>

            <?php 
            $gallery = get_post_gallery( $post, false );
            $ids = explode( ",", $gallery['ids'] );
            $hasgallery = 1;

            foreach( $ids as $id ) {
                $title = get_post_field('post_title', $id);
                $meta = get_post_field('post_excerpt', $id);
                $link = wp_get_attachment_url( $id );
                $image  = wp_get_attachment_image( $id, array( 1000, 640 ));    
            ?>

            <div class="slides">

              <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('post-theme'); ?>>

                  <div class="slide-thumb"><?php echo $image; ?></div>

              </div>

            </div><!-- .slides -->  

            <?php } ?>

        <?php else : ?>

        <?php
           $args = array(
           'post_type' => 'attachment',
           'numberposts' => -1,
           'post_status' => null,
           'post_parent' => $post->ID,
           'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
           'order' => 'ASC'
          );

          $attachments = get_posts( $args );
             if ( $attachments ) {
                foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) { ?>
                <div class="slides">
                  <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('post-theme'); ?>>
                    <div class="slide-thumb"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, array( 1000, 640 ), false, '' ); ?></div>

                  </div>
                </div>
                  <?php }
             } else {
                 ?>
                 <div class="no-slide-image"><?php _e('Images added to this page will appear here', 'restaurateur'); ?></div>
                 <?php
             } ?>

        <?php endif; ?> 

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        </div>
        <?php endif; ?> 

        </div>

        <?php $content = restaurateur_content(9999); ?>
        <?php $content = preg_replace(array('{<a[^>]*><img}','{/></a>}'), array('<img','/>'), $content); ?>
        <?php $content = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./', '', $content); ?>
        <?php $content = preg_replace('#<p>\s*+(<br\s*/*>)?\s*</p>#i', '', $content); ?>             
        <div class="intro-content">
            <?php echo $content; ?>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- end #main -->

</div> <!-- end #content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Well we need to see the php file for your homepage to be able to help. But there will be a function that calls the slider, and you'll need to move it below the text content area. Or you can just add some text ahead of that slider function yourself.

Comment: I added the php template file for the home page I'm using.  I think that should help.